# jQuery Mobile, live('pageinit', function() method to data-theme

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, attributes

In my footer, I wrote this function...

```
    jQuery('#page').live('pageinit', function() {
$('.widget ul').attr('data-inset', 'true');
$('.widget ul').attr('data-theme', 'd');
$('.widget ul').attr('data-dividertheme', 'b');
$('.widget ul').attr('data-role', 'listview');
$('.widget ul').listview();
$('a.post-edit-link').attr('data-inline', 'true');
$('a.post-edit-link').attr('data-role', 'button');
$('a.post-edit-link').button();
$('#commentform').attr('data-theme', 'e'); ...
```

So, how to apply data-theme on the last line ? What is the method, as 'listview' or 'button'?

I also wonder how to apply 'widget ul' to the first attribute...

> $('.widget ul:first')

is not working.

Thanks for your help!

Sincerely,

V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.widget ul:first` will select the first `ul` element that is a descendant of a `.widget` element. If you want to select the first list-item in `ul` then you need: `.widget ul li:first`.

Forms themselves do not get initialized by jQuery Mobile, so instead of targeting the form, you need to target the specific input widgets and initialize them.

To initialize a bunch of elements you can select them all and call `.trigger('create')` on them:

```
$('#commentform').find('input, textarea').trigger('create');
```

This gets slightly trickier when you want to update widgets rather than initialize them:

```
$('#commentform').find('input[data-type="slider"]').slider('refresh').end()
                 .find('input[type="text]').textinput('refresh').end()
                 .find('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]').checkboxradio('refresh');
```

Also you can optimize your code by chaining function calls rather than re-selecting the same element(s) multiple times:

```
$('.widget ul').attr('data-inset', 'true')
               .attr('data-theme', 'd')
               .attr('data-dividertheme', 'b')
               .attr('data-role', 'listview')
               .listview();

$('a.post-edit-link').attr('data-inline', 'true')
                     .attr('data-role', 'button')
                     .button();
```

Or you can pass an object to `.attr()` to set all of the attributes in one function call:

```
$('.widget ul').attr({
                   'data-inset'        : true,
                   'data-theme'        : 'd',
                   'data-dividertheme' : 'b',
                   'data-role'         : 'listview'
               }).listview();

$('a.post-edit-link').attr({
                         'data-inline' : true,
                         'data-role'   : 'button'
                     }).button();
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanations and your helpful advices. Now I understand better... even if the road is long! :)

Comment: @Vincent I'm wondering what about the other answer you found helped you... logically the code in the answer does the exact same thing as your code... `$('.widget').first('ul');` returns the same thing as `$('.widget ul:first')`.

Comment: And this is a great place to see chaining in effect, and shows the differences of using an Object instead of just two parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the comment form additon of data-thene isn't working...

```
jQuery('#page').live('pageinit', function() {
   var ulList = $('.widget ul'), aTag = $('a.post-edit-link')
   ulList.attr('data-inset', 'true');
   ulList.attr('data-theme', 'd');
   ulList.attr('data-dividertheme', 'b');
    ulList.attr('data-role', 'listview');
   ulList.listview();
   aTag.attr('data-inline', 'true');
   aTag.attr('data-role', 'button');
   aTag.button();
   $('#commentform').attr('data-theme', 'e'); ...
```

try that first (reason is, you don't want to parse the DOM every time for that jQuery object, save it to memory instead, it'll save processing time by a lot)... now, try this for your selection issue:

```
$('.widget').first('ul');
```

Comment: If you check-out the forms on the jQuery Mobile documentation pages you will notice that forms don't have a `data-theme` attribute to set. So setting one will most likely just be ignored by jQuery Mobile.

Comment: @Relic Thank you to you too. I regret I cannot vote for you and Jasper at the same time.